# Remove duplicates in for loop - vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a problem that I use v-for on code and image but result is duplicate, how to fix?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zVOq.png)

I'm sorry if I made you misunderstand. but you can ask me

Code

```
 <div v-for="n in follows" :key="n.follow_artist_Id">
     <div v-if="n.artist_id == sch.artist_id && n.sch_id == sch.sch_id">
         <div class="card card-schedule mb-3">
             ...
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>`

<div class="card card-schedule mb-3">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Does your `follows` array contains duplicate elements?

Comment: yes, I want `follows` to check if there is an id that is the same as `schedule_artist` to display, but if not, display the result of `schedule_artist` normal schedule_artist

Comment: It's similar to follow/unfollow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you.

For example your array like this
`products: ['Oculus', 'Google Glass', 'Microsoft Hololens', 'Oculus', 'Varjo']`

and function for remove duplication is below

```
removeDuplicates () {
  this.products = [ ...new Set(this.products) ]
}
```